# A way to know if a Firebird table's data has changed without using a trigger

Tags: firebird

Is there a way of knowing that a table's data has changed (insert/update/delete) without using a trigger on that table? Perhaps a global trigger to indicate changes on a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want notification of changes, you will need to add a trigger yourself. Firebird 3 added a new feature to simplify identifying changed rows, the pseudo-column `RDB$RECORD_VERSION`. This pseudo-column contains the transaction that created the current version of a row.

Alternatively, you could try and use the trace facility to monitor for changes, but that is not an out of the box solution, as you will need to write the necessary logic to parse the trace output (and take things like transaction commit/rollback into account).